# LWJGL and Nuklear Not Rendering Properly on Intel Graphics

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Background:  I have been working on a game engine in LWJGL.  I normally work on my desktop with an NVidia graphics card.  When using that card, everything works properly (i.e. the scene renders, UI renders, and everything updates).  However, when I use my surface pro 4 and its integrated graphics (Intel 530), the scene and UI seem to render at least 2 times (to fill both front and back buffers), then the scene and UI stop updating.  I can confirm that the application is still running, as my in console FPS counter still works.

Code:  My window's update method is as follows:

```
public void update() {
    frameRateCounter.start();
    newFrame();
    calc.layout(ctx, 50, 50);
    render(NK_ANTI_ALIASING_ON, MAX_VERTEX_BUFFER, MAX_ELEMENT_BUFFER);
    UI.poll();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    clear();
    frameRateCounter.calculate();
}
```

I use the Nuklear demo provided by LWJGL [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/tree/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/nuklear).  Does anyone have any ideas on why this is, or is this most likely a hardware issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If interested, I am working on a full jvm port of imgui [here](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems that a driver update fixed the issue.  Another issue that I just found was that the inputs seem to be several pixels off.  I can confirm this with other, 3rd party software such as Blender.  Seems that there is nothing I can do, so hopefully this response will be useful for someone else experiencing similar issues.